# pdf generated by html-pdf looks different on localhost than deployed link

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, html-pdf

I'm generating a pdf from the backend using html-pdf. The pdf looks different on local than on the deployed link on the aws ec2 server. I think pdf is not able to take inline css.
[Ec2 server generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlhNW.png)
[Locally generatedimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGD9K.png)

I want same css as on my ec2 server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.